# How to count values in group by with condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe, which was originnaly built up by 2 dataframes - `launches.merge(dropped,on=('id',how='left')`, so in result I got

```
id name colour dropped
1   K    pink    1
2   K    red     1
3   L    blue    1
4   M    red    NaN
5   K    pink    1
6   K    pink   NaN
```

where column dropped came from the dataframe with dropes(it's a flag)
In result I want to get dataframe like this

```
name colour launches  dropped
K    pink    3          2
K    red     1          1
L    blue    1          1
M    red     1          0
```

I tried the following

```
df = d.groupby(['name','colour']).count()
```

Comment: ``df.assign(launches = df.dropped.ffill()).groupby(['name', 'colour'], as_index = False)[['dropped', 'launches']].sum()``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) to do the count and sum separately :

```
(df.groupby(['name', 'colour'])
   .agg(launches = ('dropped', 'size'), 
        dropped = ('dropped', 'sum'))
   .reset_index()
)

             
name colour    launches  dropped
K    pink           3      2.0
     red            1      1.0
L    blue           1      1.0
M    red            1      0.0
```

Another option, thanks to @HenryEcker, is to use a count, instead of a sum, since `count` ignores nulls, and returns integers :

```
(df.groupby(['name', 'colour'])
   .agg(launches=('dropped', 'size'), 
        dropped=('dropped', 'count'))
   .reset_index()
)
Out[135]:
             
name colour  launches  dropped
K    pink           3        2
     red            1        1
L    blue           1        1
M    red            1        0
```

Comment: Could also agg with `count` instead of `sum` since `count` only counts non-NaN values. `df.groupby(['name', 'colour'], as_index=False).agg(launches=('colour', 'size'), dropped=('dropped', 'count'))` keeps the `dtype` as `int` instead of `float`.

Comment: Thank you! still can't get why do you use size and only colour in lunches? If I have more columns in group by which should I choose

Comment: `size` is always the same. It is the number of rows within the group. You could've used `dropped` too. Makes no difference here any valid column works. However, `count`/`sum` must be the specific column since you're specifically trying to count the non-NaN values in the column.

Comment: You can use `dropped` and `size` together, since it would not ignore null values.

Comment: @sammywemmy, Is where a way another way to do it? The thing is that after this I convert it to sql table with built-in function, and I get only two columns - launches and dropped-instead of all four

Comment: I think you need a `reset.index` at the end